# No renderiza una plantilla html con Flask, pero tampoco da errores

Tags: html, flask

Estoy intentando desde una plantilla html recoger el resultado de un botón. Este es mi código html de la plantilla:

```html
<div class="row g-0 w-100 mt-4">
    <form id="miformulario" method="POST">
            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" onclick="prepararDatos()">Exportar</button>
            </div>
    <div class="col-12">

        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sortable" id="parts-table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th id="selection-state-head"><input type="checkbox" role="button" onclick="selectAllRows(this)" style="margin:10%;"></th>
                    <th class="sortable both" role="button" scope="col" id="date-head">Fecha</th>
                    <th scope="col">Dedicación</th>
                    <th class="sortable both" role="button" scope="col" id="type-head">Tipo de tarea</th>
                    <th scope="col">Estado de tarea</th>
                    <th class="sortable both" role="button" id="employee-head" scope="col">Técnico</th>
                    <th class="sortable both" role="button" id="customer-head" scope="col">Cliente</th>
                    <th id="work-head" scope="col">Tarea</th>
                    <th scope="col">Descripción</th>
                    <th scope="col">Conforme</th>
                    <th scope="col">Observación</th>
                    <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                    {% if g.employee %}
                    <th id="edit-btn-head" scope="col">Ver/Editar</th>
                    {% endif %}
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    {%for line in lines%}
                        <tr>
                            <td class="selection-state">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" onclick="selectRow(this)" role="button"  style="margin:10%;"  value="{{line.id}}">
                            </td>
                            <td id="line_work-id" style="display:none;">{{ line.id }}</td>
                            <td id="line_date"  scope="row" style="width: 100px">{{ line.fecha }}</td>
                            <td id="line_duration" >{{ (line.dedicacion|string)[:-3] }}</td>
                            <td id="line_work-type" style="width: 140px">{{ line.tipo_tarea}}</td>
                            <td id="line_status"  style="width: 140px">{{ line.estado_tarea}}</td>
                            <td id="line_employee">{{ line.tecnico}}</td>
                            <td id="line_party" >{{ line.cliente}}</td>
                            <td id="line_work" >{{ line.tarea }}</td>
                            <td id="line_description">{{ line.descripcion }}</td>
                            <!-- aqui van los radio button -->
                            <td id="line_according_{{ line.id }}">
                                <input type="radio" id="yes_{{ line.id }}" name="conforme_{{ line.id }}" value="yes" onclick="showCommentBoxYes('{{ line.id }}', this.id)">                                 <label for="yes_{{ line.id }}">S</label>
                                <input type="radio" id="no_{{ line.id }}" name="conforme_{{ line.id }}" value="no" onclick="showCommentBoxNo('{{ line.id }}', this.id)">
                                <label for="no_{{ line.id }}">N</label>
                                <span id="selection_{{ line.id }}"></span> <!-- Aquí se mostrará la selección -->
                            </td>
                            <td id="line_commentBox">
                                {% for comentario in comentaries %}
                                    {{ comentario.text }}
                                {% endfor %}
                            </td>
                            <td id="line_name">
                                <a href="/events?event_param={{ line.id }}">
                                [EP] En proceso</a></td>
                            <td id="line_internal-description" style="display:none;">{{ line.editor_ver }}</td>
                            {% if g.employee %}
                            <td>
                                <button type="button" class="edit-btn btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Editar
                                </button>
                            </td>

                        </tr>

                    {% endif %}
                    <tr id="time-count" style="height: 35px;" colspan="10">
                        <td></td><td></td>
                        <td id="time-cell"></td>
                        <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                        {% if g.employee %}
                        <td></td>
                        {% endif %}
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="datos_seleccionados" id="dataInput">
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

He hecho dos scripts, uno para cada botón, solo pondré el de "sí":

```js
function showCommentBoxYes(lineId, buttonId) {
    console.log(buttonId);
    console.log("Función showCommentBoxYes llamada para la línea ID:", lineId);
    var yesRadioButton = document.getElementById(buttonId);
    var yesChecked = yesRadioButton.checked;
    console.log("¿El botón 'Sí' está marcado?", yesChecked);

    // Crear un objeto con los datos que se enviarán al servidor
    var requestData = {
        lineId: lineId,
        text: "OK, está de acuerdo con lo realizado"
    };

    // Enviar la solicitud al servidor y manejar la respuesta
    sendRequest("/commentBox", requestData)
        .then(handleServerResponse)
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error("Error al enviar la solicitud:", error);
        });
    sendRequest("/commentBox", requestData)
        .then(handleServerResponse)
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error("Error al enviar la solicitud:", error);
        });
}

function sendRequest(url, data) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    resolve(xhr.responseText);
                    window.open("prueba.html", "_blank");
                } else {
                    reject(xhr.statusText);
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
}

function handleServerResponse(response) {
    // Actualizar el DOM con la respuesta del servidor
    console.log("Respuesta del servidor:", response);
    // Aquí puedes manipular el DOM según la respuesta recibida
}
```

La función que hace que recoge el botón "sí", le da un mensaje estático y luego lo reenvía a un método flask:

```py
@app.route('/commentBox', methods=['POST'])
def commentBox():
    comentaries = []
    #pdb.set_trace()
    data = request.get_json()
    lineId = data.get('lineId')
    yesChecked = data.get('yesChecked')
    noChecked = data.get('noChecked')
    comment = data.get('comment')
    # Añadir el comentario a la lista
    comentaries.append({'lineId': lineId, 'text': comment})
    print(comentaries)
    return render_template('exportar3.html', comentarios=comentaries)
```

Este método recoge cada uno de los campos que necesita y lo agrega a una lista con un diccionario, luego mediante el `render_template` vuelve a enviarlo una plantilla para que lo muestre en pantalla:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block body %}
<h2> Hemos entrado en la plantilla de destino </h2>

{% for comentario in comentarios %}
    <p>lineId: {{ comentario['lineId'] }}</p>
    <p>text: {{ comentario['text'] }}</p>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock body %}
```

Cuando ejecuto la app, en la terminal me aparece como manda los datos:

> [{'lineId': '4', 'text': 'Hola'}]
> 127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2024 10:05:41] "POST /commentBox HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Pero no me abre la plantilla ni me muestra nada. He revisado todo, le he hecho un debugger con `pdb.set_trace()`, y aunque todo me da correcto es imposible que lo muestre. He mirado también en la consola del navegador y en la respuesta que da sí me aparece tal y como debería aparecer la plantilla.

¿Qué es lo que puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 0):

estoy acostumbrado utilizar fetch pero podria a simple vista la funcion de vista que estas utilizando con el metodo post no es para mostrar contenido al cliente entonces deberia redirecionar al cliente otra funcion de vista con tu plantilla html